# Select Line 3 and Display line 3 TextFile BatchScript

Tags: command-line

i want,display only line 3 of Textfile

```
C:\Program Files
C:\Program Files (x86)
C:\Users
C:\Windows



@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (text.txt) do (
    echo %%b
)
pause
```

[thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5O3c.png)

Answer (score 0):

For help try execute `if /?` on the command line. And `set /?`.
What you need is a counter variable which is increased in your for loop. And an if statement that checks if the value is 3 for example and then echos %%b.